# I have tried everything, please help. After moving Wordpress, category archives are broken

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, categories, permalinks

I just moved my Wordpress site to a different server and url. All the posts are showing up in the dashboard, and I can view them individually on the site, but they aren't showing up on the category archives.

For example, when I look at the 'Advocacy' category in the admin panel, it says that it contains 8 posts, but when I click "View" the category archive page says "Nothing Found".

Any idea how I can fix this? Sorry if this is a poorly written question but I'm completely at a loss as to why this is happening.

You can view it here:
http://www.carolinafarmstewards.org/cfsa-test/

Update ***_*__*_*__**

I've read through the Moving WordPress direction and tried the solutions listed there. I've tried checking the [.htaccess file](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/permalinks-broken-after-blog-move?replies=7), [resetting the permalinks](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/after-moved-wordpress-to-new-domain-category-038-permalinks-broken?replies=2), and even adding this [bit of code to the wp-config.php file](http://jeffsebring.com/fixing-broken-permalinks-when-moving-wordpress/). Nothing helps. I'm at a loss.

Another Update ***_*__*_*__**

I've tried replacing every instance of the old url. I used Search and Replace and Velvet Blue Update Urls. It fixed a lot of instances, but everything is still broken.

Yet Another Update  ***_*____**

I have tried using a clean wordpress install on the new server and importing the data using wordpress' import tool. Same result. You can see that version here: (carolinafarmstewards.org/newsite)

Updating again  ***_*__*_*_**

I ran through all the fixes again this morning. Just to make sure I didn't miss anything. No change. Does anyone have any ideas?

I just noticed something  ***_*__*_*__*_*___**

This is basically another way of describing the problem, but I just noticed this and thought it might be helpful in diagnosing what's going on. From the admin panel, when I am looking at the posts list, all the posts say they are assigned to categories, but when I try to filter the posts list by any category, it says "No posts found."

Comment: Have you gone in to your Permalinks settings in the dashboard and re-saved them? Sometimes the htaccess file gets missed when moving sites.

Comment: Yes, I changed the permalinks settings, saved them, and then changed them back to what they should be and saved them. It doesn't seem to have made any difference.

Comment: I would search for the old URL in the database, to see if there are any traces left.

Comment: Yes, I tried that too. I used Search and Replace and Velvet Blue Update Urls. It fixed a lot of instances, but everything is still broken.

Comment: I don't know how you moved Wordpress, but I would install it freshly on the target server, use WP's export/import features, and try it once more.

Comment: I tried that too. Didn't think it was worth mentioning. Same result. (carolinafarmstewards.org/newsite)

Comment: This question belongs to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Have you changed the `wp-options` table in your mysql to reflect the new url?

Comment: Yes I've checked the database through myphpadmin. There are no more instances of the old url anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I kind of feel like an idiot, and I still don't know why it broke, but...

If I use a different theme, the categories work. I'm kind of perturbed because my theme was working before the move. I'm still not sure why that theme seems to break the categories now that it's on a new server, but it does.

Comment: Look at the logs. At a guess, the new server is on a different version of PHP, and the theme uses a function that works on one version but not on another.